# How to get the unmatched lines in vimdiff

Tags: diff, vimdiff

I am comparing a list of packages for a Django project in production and development. There are inconsistency in versions, but I am only concerned about the packages that got installed independently on another. So I am trying to get lines that are not matched (noted with -----) in vimdiff.

I can whip a python or perl script to do this, but I was wondering if there is a command line tool or achieve the same thing in Vim, because I think this can be useful for auditing other file sin the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Returns only lines with unique first word:**

```
cut -d ' ' -f1 input?.txt | sort | uniq -u
```

**input1.txt:**

```
package1 v1
package2 v1
package3 v1
package4 v1
package5 v1
```

**input2.txt:**

```
package1 v1
package2 v2
package4 v4
package5 v5
```

**output:**

```
package3
```